# Excel formula use variable as row reference in other sheet

Tags: excel, function

Would appreciate any assistance with this.

I have formula:

```
=INDEX('data'!$10:$10,(ROW(1:1)+4))
```

This is referencing my data sheet row 10 and column 5 ( The $10:$10 is a reference to ROW and the (ROW(1:1)+5) is providing the reference to column 5.

To make things scale more easily I would very much like to replace the $10:$10 part (the row) with the value from a cell which is on the current sheet, not in the data sheet. The reason for this is that I am able to calculate the co-ordinates from another formula on the existing sheet.

So, in summary instead of:

```
=INDEX('data'!$10:$10,(ROW(1:1)+4))
```

I would like to use something like:

```
=INDEX('data'!(REFERENCE TO A VALUE IN A LOCAL SHEET CELL),(ROW(1:1)+4))
```

The value in the local cell is a valid integer which represents the correct row the formula should point to in the 'data' sheet. Hope this makes sense.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use INDIRECT() and concatenate.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(concatenate ("'data'!$", A1, ":$", A1)),(ROW(1:1)+4))
```

If A1 is where the row number is

Comment: Fantastic. I had seen the INDIRECT function but not understood it properly till you demonstrated how it could be used here. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind INDIRECT is a volatile function. That means it will recalculate every time you change something on the sheet. Use INDIRECT only when you must or the workbook will be slow.